# How to refer to redirection file from within a bash script?

Tags: bash, redirect

I'd like to write a bash script myscript such that issuing this command:

myscript > filename.txt

would return the name of the filename that it's output is being redirected to, filename.txt.  Is this possible?

Comment: No, the script does not have access to that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running on Linux, check where `/proc/self/fd/1` links to.

For example, the script can do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
readlink /proc/self/fd/1
```

And then run it:

```
$ ./myscript > filename.txt
$ cat filename.txt
/tmp/filename.txt
```

Note that if you want to save the value of the output file to a variable or something, you can't use `/proc/self` since it will be different in the subshell, but you can still use `$$`:

```
outputfile=$(readlink /proc/$$/fd/1)
```

Comment: I'm guessing this would be a bit faster than the lsof approach since it doesn't have to spawn awk.

Answer (score 1):

Using `lsof`:

```
outfile=$(lsof -p $$ | awk '/1w/{print $NF}')
echo $outfile
```